# AutoHotKey - Getting `files to loop, following documentation

Tags: autohotkey

I am making a program in AHK that extracts Steam prices and Bitcoin addresses from there store website. I am storing all of my accounts in a text file the same directory as the script.

Right now when I run the program, nothing happens when I click the start button, nothing happens. Earlier I tried using a function that loops through and reads the file line by line but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code. I am very new to AHK. I followed the example in the documentation [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopReadFile.htm) and I am not sure why it is not working. Please help!

```
#SingleInstance, Force

;; GUI input
: -------------------------------
: ---------------------------------------
Gui, Show, w300 h300, Steam Tool    
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y20 gStart, Start the tool
return

; Labels
; -----------------------
; --------------------------------

Start:    
Loop, read accounts,.txt
{
    loop, parse, LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
    {                
        Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Multiloginapp\multiloginapp.exe
        WinWait, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        Sleep, 20000
        WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        IfWinNotActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15, ,WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        Click 724 260
        sleep, 1500
        WinWait, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        WinActivate, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        Click 408 55
        Sleep 5000
        Send, ^a
        Send,{Backspace}
        Send, store.steampowered.com/account
        Send, {enter}
        MsgBox %LoopReadLine%
    }
}
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir% ; if an absolute path isn't specified

;; GUI input
;-------------------------------
; ---------------------------------------
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y20 gStart, Start the tool
Gui, Show, w300 h300, Steam Tool    
return

; Labels
; -----------------------
; --------------------------------

Start:    
Loop, read, accounts.txt    ; the file name must be separated by a comma
{
    ; MsgBox %A_LoopReadLine%
    loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
    {                
        IfWinNotExist, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        { 
            Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Multiloginapp\multiloginapp.exe
            WinWait, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
            Sleep, 20000
        }
        IfWinNotActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15, ,WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        Click 724, 260
        sleep, 1500
        WinWait, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        WinActivate, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        Click 408, 55
        Sleep 5000
        Send, ^a
        Send, {Backspace}
        SendInput, store.steampowered.com/account    ; SendInput is faster in sending text
        Send, {enter}
        ; Use:
        ; SendInput, %A_LoopField%
        ; if you want to send the current substring (field) from the line
        MsgBox %A_LoopField%
    }
}
return
```